# Displaying MySQL data in <select> failing

Tags: php, mysql

I am simply trying to display an html `<select>` drop down that displays options from MySQL database rows. As far as I can tell this should be working. However, it is not displaying anything in the drop down. the `campaigns` table definitely has data in the `campaignid` and `name` columns. Not sure why it isn't display anything. Please help.

#### the form that should display `name`

```
<?php
//include db connect
  include ("db_con.php");



   //campaign change form function
  function changeCampaign() {
    //set variables
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM campaigns");
    //echo form
    echo '<table border="1">
          <form action="functions/campaign_change.php" name="campaignChange" method="post">
            <tr>
              <td><select name="campaignList">';
                    //loop campaigns
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                      echo "<option value='" . $row['campaignid'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
                    }
        echo '</select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="submit" value="Load" /></td>
            </tr>
          </form>
        </table>';
}
?>
```

And then I am simply calling the `changeCampaign();` function, which IS displaying the form with `<select>` just no content in it.

### The following code was added to show a successful script adding to the same table

#### here is the form to create a `campaign`

```
//campaign creation form function
  function createCampaign() {
    echo '<table border="1">
          <form action="functions/campaign_create.php" name="campaignCreate" method="post">
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Campaign Name" required /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><center><input type="submit" name="Create" /></center></td>
            </tr>
          </form>
          </table>';
}
```

#### campaign_create.php

```
<?php
//include db connect
  include ("db_con.php");

//start session
  session_start();

//set variable names
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  $campaignname = addslashes($_POST['name']);

//validate campaign name length
  if ((strlen($campaignname) < 6) || (strlen($campaignname) > 55)) {
    echo 'Campaign name must be between 6 and 55 characters - Please go back and try again.';
    exit;
  }

//create new campaign
  $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO campaigns (creator, name) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$campaignname."')");
  if ($query) {
    echo 'Campaign created successfully!';
    header( "refresh:2;url=../index.php" );
  } else {
    echo 'There was an unknown error in creating the campaign - Please go back and try again.';
  }

?>
```

P.S. - Yes, `campaignid` is a row in the table, and does have data in it.

Comment: your `<select>` tag isn't closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `<select>` HTML tag is never closed with a `</select>`.

Second, the `$con` variable is not usable from within the `changeCampaign` function scope.  Add `global $con;` to the beginning of the function to fix it.

Additionally, I prefer to jump in and out of PHP blocks with this kind of stuff.  Consider this code:

```
<?php
//include db connect
include ("db_con.php");

//campaign change form function
    function changeCampaign() {
    global $con; // we need the connection data in here.
    //set variables
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM campaigns");
?>
<table border="1">
    <form action="functions/campaign_change.php" name="campaignChange" method="post">
        <tr>
            <td><select name="campaignList">';
<?php
                    //loop that is NOT displaying the name
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['campaignid'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
                    }
?>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Load" /></td>
        </tr>
        </form>
    </table>';
<?php
}
?>
```

In this, you have HTML code that is outputted just as if it had been `echo`ed, but it is much nicer.

Comment: That was dumb of me to forget the closing `</select>` tag. However, in adding it, it still is not displaying the name.

Comment: Can you tell if the `while` loop even being run?  Also, are there any errors?

Comment: If by the 'for' loop, you meant the 'while' loop, it does not appear to be running. Also, no errors that I am aware of.

Comment: Ok i tried to make a variable `$num = mysqli_num_rows($query)` and echoed the variable `$num` it was just blank. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: I added `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning. It returned nothing. 

I have also added some code that I use to create a campaign which is accessing the same table of the same database. This works just fine. I am totally confused here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo a close select tag. Just add this line after your loop and you'll be fine

```
echo '</select>';
```

Also try changing the first line of your loop to this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($con, $query)) {
```

Comment: No problem, I did this myself a few weeks ago

Comment: Ok, actually closing `<select>` did not help... I updated the original post with new code.